# Sending large file with httpwebrequest: Request-URI to long

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I made a wrapper to send and receive data to and from the webserver. So far it works but when I try to use it to send something with a file byte array (a pdf or word doc) in it it fails and gives me the message **Request-URI to long**

This is the code for the wrapper:

```
  public class CallWebService
{
    public enum Methods
    {
        GET = 1,
        POST = 2,
        PUT = 3,
        DELETE = 4
    }

    //public TResult ExecutionResult { get; set; }
    public string WebServiceURL { get; set; }
    public Methods Method { get; set; }

    public CallWebService(string sWebServiceUrl)
    {
        this.WebServiceURL = sWebServiceUrl;
    }

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(string sCommand, Methods mMethod)
    {
        return Execute<TResult, string>(sCommand, mMethod, null);
    }

    public TResult Execute<TResult, TParam>(string sCommand, Methods mMethod, TParam parameter)
    {
        TResult executionResult = default(TResult);
        string requestUriString = "";
        try
        {
            if (this.WebServiceURL != null)
            {
                requestUriString = Path.Combine(this.WebServiceURL, sCommand); 

                JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                jsonSerializer.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
                string jsonParameter = null;
                if (parameter != null)
                {
                    jsonParameter = jsonSerializer.Serialize(parameter);
                    requestUriString += "?" + jsonParameter;
                }

                HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(requestUriString) as HttpWebRequest;
                req.KeepAlive = false;
                req.Method = mMethod.ToString().ToUpper();

                Stream dataStream;

                if (("POST,PUT").Split(',').Contains(mMethod.ToString().ToUpper()))
                {
                    if (jsonParameter != null && jsonParameter.ToString().Length > 0)
                    {
                        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonParameter);
                        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
                        req.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
                        req.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                        // Get the request stream.
                        dataStream = req.GetRequestStream();
                        // Write the data to the request stream.
                        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                        // Close the Stream object.
                        dataStream.Close();
                    }
                }
                // Get the response.
                HttpWebResponse response = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
                // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
                dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                // Read the content.
                string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                // Clean up the streams.
                reader.Close();
                dataStream.Close();
                response.Close();
                executionResult = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<TResult>(responseFromServer);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("WebServiceURL not provided. Please initialize the object first.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          //To Do
        }
        return executionResult;
    }
}
```

}

Any help is appreciated

Comment: It looks like you're *always* appending the parameter onto the query string and then (for POST and PUT) *also* putting it in the request body. Generally, it should only go in the query string for GETs. Also, you should almost always include a language tag on your questions. It *looks* like it's probably [tag:c#] but you shouldn't force potential helpers to either a) guess, or b) not even see your question.

Comment: Boom spot on..thanks for the eagle eye !
Thanks for the language comment!